# Parsing out a line in R to pick different objects

Tags: regex, r

I have this line:

```
system<-c("System configuration: type=Shared mode=Uncapped smt=4 lcpu=96 mem=393216MB psize=64 ent=16.00")
```

I need to parse out this and pick smt, lcpu, mem, mpsize and ent into different objects.

For example, I doing this to pick the smt, but it picks the whole line, any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

```
smt<-sub('^.* smt=([[:digit:]])', '\\1', system)
```

smt needs to have a number 4 in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `.*` to the end of your matching expression and you'll get "4".

```
sub('^.* smt=([[:digit:]]+).*', '\\1', system)
```

You may want to add the `+` I included in the instance where it is more than a single digit.

You could also approach this by splitting on spaces and the finding the matches:

```
splits <- unlist(strsplit(system, ' '))
sub('smt=', '', grep('smt=', splits, value=TRUE))
# [1] "4"
```

or wrapping it in a function:

```
matchfun <- function(string, to_match, splitter=' ') {
  splits <- unlist(strsplit(string, splitter))
  sub(to_match, '', grep(to_match, splits, value=TRUE))
}

matchfun(system, 'smt=')
# [1] "4"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `strsplit` a couple times, and `type.convert`:

```
parse.config <- function(x) {
   clean  <- sub("System configuration: ", "", x)
   pairs  <- strsplit(clean, " ")[[1]]
   items  <- strsplit(pairs, "=")
   keys   <- sapply(items, `[`, 1)
   values <- sapply(items, `[`, 2)
   values <- lapply(values, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
   setNames(values, keys)
}

config <- parse.config(system)
# $type
# [1] "Shared"
# 
# $mode
# [1] "Uncapped"
# 
# $smt
# [1] 4
# 
# $lcpu
# [1] 96
# 
# $mem
# [1] "393216MB"
# 
# $psize
# [1] 64
# 
# $ent
# [1] 16
```

The output is a list so you can access any of the parsed items, for example:

```
config$smt
# [1] 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `strapplyc` in the [gusbfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) the following creates a list `L` whose names are the left hand sides such as `smt` and whose values are the right hand sides.

```
library(gsubfn)

LHS <- strapplyc( system, "(\\w+)=" )[[1]]
RHS <- strapplyc( system, "=(\\w+)" )[[1]]
L <- setNames( as.list(RHS), LHS )
```

For example we can now get `smt` like this (and similarly for the other left hand sides):

```
> L$smt
[1] "4"
```

UPDATE: Simplified.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm voting for @GaborGrothendieck's, but am offering this as a more pedestrian alternative:

```
inp <- c("System configuration: type=Shared mode=Uncapped smt=4 lcpu=96 mem=393216MB psize=64 ent=16.00")
inparsed <- read.table(text=inp, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
vals <- unlist(inparsed)[grep("\\=", unlist(inparsed))]
vals
#           V3            V4            V5            V6            V7            V8            V9 
#  type=Shared mode=Uncapped         smt=4       lcpu=96  mem=393216MB      psize=64     ent=16.00 
vals[grep("smt|lcpu|mem|mpsize|ent", vals)]
            V5             V6             V7             V9 
       "smt=4"      "lcpu=96" "mem=393216MB"    "ent=16.00"
```

I would note that choosing the name 'system' for a variable seems most unwise in light of the `system` function's existence.